# Normalizing Wave Functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, normalization

We normalize the wave function to $1$, but couldn't we also normalize it to $-i$ as $(-i)^2=1$?

Does this not work? Is it equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

Normalizing $\psi$ to $1$ means that we ensure that

$$
\int|\psi|^2dx = 1
$$

normalizing it to $-i$ would presumably mean ensuring that

$$
\int|\psi|^2dx = -i
$$

which is impossible because the integrand $|\psi|^2$ is positive everywhere.

Comment: Oh whoops... Haha... Okay, can we just normalize to $-1$ then? I guess that doesn't matter.

Comment: And do we always normalize the square? Why not just the normal wave function?

Comment: I agree with this answer. The phrase "normalize the wave function" is very, very common; it's also a little misleading. Indeed, you make sure the integral of the *absolute value squared* is equal to $1$, not the integral of the wave function itself.

Comment: @BMS I wouldn't say it's misleading because the term "normalize" arises from setting the _norm_ of something equal to 1. But there are different kinds of norms, and the details of what it means to normalize depend entirely on which kind of norm you're using. For example the standard norm of a vector $\mathbf{v}$ is $\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2}$; the standard norm of a wavefunction is $\sqrt{\int\lvert\psi\rvert^2}$. If you set $\int|\psi| = 1$ instead, you wouldn't be using the norm. (Well, it'd be _a_ norm, the L1 norm, which is rather arcane and sees essentially no use in physics.)

Comment: Since the integrand is positive everywhere, how can we normalize to $-1$? We normalize the square because $|\psi(x)|^2dx$  is the probability of finding the particle in the small interval $(x,x+dx)$; hence $\int |\psi|^2 dx$ is the probability of finding the probability  in the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$, which better be $1$.

Comment: @David Z. Interesting! I've always taken "norm" here to refer strictly to the number "1" rather than the *norm* of a quantity equal to 1. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Tony Actually there is an interesting discussion around this. If you have real positive functions which norm to 1 in the the so-called L1 norm $\int |\psi| = 1$, you get ordinary probability theory. If you do the L2 norm $\int |\psi|^2 = 1$ that's QM and interesting. You could also ask about Lp norms $\int |\psi|^p = 1$ for any $p$... but turns out that only $p=1,2$ make any sense because of a thing called Gleason's theorem (I'm brushing past some technicalities - the moral is right).

Comment: (cont.) So in a sense QM is the *only* other thing you could have besides ordinary probabilities. Mathematicians could have discovered it in the 1800s without having to wait for experiment if they knew where to look! :) See [here](http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec9.html) and links therein for details.